# Getting NULL for a row a type nvarchar when I try to use LINQ to mirror my database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a table created with

```
CREATE TABLE orgs ( O_Id int NOT NULL identity(1,1), orgname nvarchar (MAX) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (O_Id) );
```

and a few rows of it then initialized with

```
INSERT INTO orgs (orgname) VALUES ('someOrg');
INSERT INTO orgs (orgname)  VALUES ('otherOrg');
```

I've looked in Visual Studio's Server Object Explorer to make sure the table and its columns and the 2 rows were successfully created.

My model that mirrors this table is

```
[Table(Name = "orgs")]
public class Organization
{
    public Organization()
    {

    }

    [Column]
    public int O_Id { get; set; }
    public string orgname { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller I have, a test,

```
PortalData PD = new PortalData();
foreach (Organization x in PD.orgs)
{
    ViewBag.orgsInfo += ("O_id=" + (x.O_Id).ToString() + ", org=" + x.orgname + "\n");
}
```

The problem is that `(x.O_Id).ToString()` is spitting out the correct value but `x.orgname` is undefined.

My hypothesis is that this has something to do with an intermediate conversion that needs to take place for the data type of the column to be used as a C# string.

EDIT: Added code for PortalData below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace AllyPortal.Models
{
    [Database]
    public class PortalData : DataContext
    {
        public PortalData()
            : base("...")
        {
        }
        public Table<AssetLink> links;
        public Table<AssetFile> files;
        public Table<Organization> orgs;
        public Table<Category> cats;       

    }   

    [Table( Name = "links")]
    public class AssetLink
    {
        public AssetLink()
        {

        }

        [Column]
        public int rownum { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public int linkid { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public int fileid { get; set; }

    }

    [Table( Name = "files" )]
    public class AssetFile
    {
        public AssetFile()
        {

        }

        [Column]
        public int fileid { get; set; }
        public string org { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }
        public string loc { get; set; }
    }

    [Table(Name = "orgs")]
    public class Organization
    {
        public Organization()
        {

        }

        [Column]
        public int O_Id { get; set; }
        public string orgname { get; set; }
    }  

   [Table(Name = "cats")]
    public class Category
    {
        public Category()
        {

        }

        [Column]
        public int O_Id { get; set; }
        public string cat { get; set; }
    }  

}
```

Comment: By the way, let me know if you guys need me to provide any more information

Comment: Can you post the code of PortalData, please?

Comment: @CodeNotFound Yes, I'll post it (with some stuff anonymized)

Comment: Do you not need a `[Column]` attribute on *all* of the properties?

Answer (score 1):

From [the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Use this attribute to designate a member of an entity class to represent a column in a database table. ... Only those entity class members identified as columns are persisted when LINQ to SQL saves changes to the database.

That would suggest that you need to add the `[Column]` attribute to *all* of the properties in your `AssetFile`, `Organization` and `Category` classes. Without the attribute, the value of those properties will not be loaded from, or persisted to, the database.